# Binding property on a parent property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I work on a WPF application and I use the PropertyGrid object from XCEED (advanced WPF).

I create a class called "SynopticItem" which derived from ContentControl.
In the "Content" property, there is an object like Rectangle, Ellipse, ...

I want to know if it's possible to bind (XAML side), the "Width" property of my object present in the "Content" property with the "Width" property of my "SynopticItem" class property.

I tried something like :

```
<xceedToolkit:DoubleUpDown Value="{Binding Path=Width, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:SynopticItem}}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: detailed binding warnings and errors are displayed in the output window in visual studio. it's a good start when debugging bindings.

Comment: There is not enough context to answer the question, nor does the question make sense. In general, you can refer to known objects and bind to their properties. So it probably can work. But when you write _"my object"_, it seems like that is in fact your _"SynopticItem"_ object, so you seem to be asking to bind that object's `Width` property to itself. The XAML on the other hand appears to try to bind the `Width` to a `Value` property in the library object. Without [a good, _minimal_, _complete_ code example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's not feasible to offer an answer.